# Why won't this java 8 code compile?

Tags: eclipse, lambda, java-8

```
public static Stream<Cell> streamCells(int rows, int cols) {
    return IntStream.range(0, rows).mapToObj(row -> IntStream.range(0, cols).mapToObj(col -> new Cell(row, col)));
}
```

I'm using Eclipse. The following error is given by eclipse.

```
Type mismatch: cannot convert from Stream<Object> to Stream<ProcessArray.Cell>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An alternative solution to @flo's

```
public static Stream<Cell> streamCells(int rows, int cols) {
    return IntStream.range(0, rows).boxed()
            .flatMap(row -> IntStream.range(0, cols).mapToObj(col -> new Cell(row, col)));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your Code maps to a Stream of Streams. Deviding it into declaration and return provides the following code:

```
Stream<Stream<Cell>> mapToObj = IntStream.range(0, rows).mapToObj(row -> IntStream.range(0, cols).mapToObj(col -> new Cell(row, col)));
return mapToObj;
```

You need to reduce your Streams to a single Stream:

```
// CAVE: poor performance
return IntStream.range(0, rows)
    .mapToObj(row -> IntStream.range(0, cols).mapToObj(col -> new Cell(row, col)))
    .reduce(Stream.empty(), Stream::concat);
```

**Edit:** As pointed out by Holger in the comments, reducing a Stream of Streams with Stream.concat() is not very performant. Use one of the other solutions utilizing the `flatMap` method instead of `reduce`.

Comment: Your code gives me `Type mismatch: cannot convert from Stream<Object> to Stream<ProcessArray.Cell>`.

Comment: Sorry, your answer was correct. The error was due to an Eclipse bug. Marking your answer as correct.

Comment: Don’t do this. Using `Stream.concat` for a higher number of streams will be a performance disaster. It implies that all sub-streams are instantiated eagerly before the resulting stream is returned and they will be referenced by the `concat`entated stream during its lifetime. Use `Stream.flatMap` which is intended for this use. It will not instantiate any sub-stream before the actual terminal operation requires it. It also allows the sub-streams to get garbage collection right after use.

Comment: @Hoger Thanks for your input. Edited. That's the result of answering directly after getting up and before the first coffee. :-) Luckily, the OP has found an appropriate solution by himself and posted it as answer.

Comment: @Hoger In that case I will mark my answer as the correct one so as not to mislead anyone who visits this.

Answer (score 1):

@flo's answer, reworked to use flatMap instead (flatMap "embeds" the Stream returned by the flatMapping function into the original stream):

```
return IntStream.range(0, rows)
  .mapToObj(row -> IntStream.range(0, cols)
    .mapToObj(col -> new Cell(row, col))
  ) // int -> Stream<Cell>
  .flatmap(Function.identity()) // Stream<Cell> -> Cell
;
```